# Date conversion issue only in chrome

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which contains a date/time parameter. This parameter has a default value set like below:

```
=CDATE(Format(Today,"dd/MM/yyyy") & " " & Format(Globals!ExecutionTime,"HH:mm:ss"))
```

When I launch the report in Internet Explorer is working but not in chrome which throws below message error:

```
The DefaultValue expression for the report parameter 'initial_date' contains an error: Conversion from string "20/05/2016 10:04:20" to type 'Date' is not valid (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is there a reason why you aren't using the following as your default for your parameter: `=now()`
2. Are you comparing Chrome and IE on the same machine.

This works for me on both browsers.

Comment: I need to display date and also time so I am using CDate(....). Are you mean that replacing all by =now() will display date and time as default value in date/time parameter according culture browser automatically? Yes, I am using Chrome and IE on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have IEinTab installed on chrome? Get it installed then run the report again.

SSRS relies on IE's render engine to do alot of the work, chrome just fails on it without IEinTab.

Comment: ok, thanks very much. And is there any other alternative? any configuration in google chrome in order to work? or any other function different from CDate that can work in both, IE and Chrome?

Comment: No alternative or configuration, its just how Microsoft do things :( BIdeveloper is correct in saying use =now() in your script.

Comment: glad to hear it :)